# Exporting certain rows from a csv to a new csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file, and am trying to place all of the rows that are from the month of June into a new csv file. This is what I have so far, with the 10th column being the date column of the csv. However, when I try to run this I get the error: `IndexError: string index out of range`

```
with open(filename) as csvin:
    readfile = csv.reader(csvin, delimiter=',')    
    with open(summer, 'wb') as csvout:
        writefile = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        for row in readfile:
            datetime = row[10] 
            if datetime[0] == '6': 
                writefile.writerow(row)
```

If I just `print datetime` instead of the if statement inside the loop, the code prints out all of the dates correctly. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Something is very wrong with your indentation...

Comment: We can't see `datetime` but I'm guessing it's a string that is 6 or fewer characters long.` For example, 1st June might be 01/06?

Comment: You should not use `datetime` as a name for your variables, Python already uses it.

Comment: @roganjosh datetime prints out in the format of m/dd/yyyy if it's a 1 digit month and mm/dd/yyyy if it's a 2 digit month. (I realized this is not a good thing to have but I am only dealing with single digit months right now)

Comment: add a `pdb` break point before the erroneous line and check its value, seems like you're getting an empty string at some point (hence the `IndexError`).

Comment: its possible that not every row has a date